# Does Google AppEngine Standard support java CDI?

Tags: google-app-engine, cdi

I am trying to create a java web application for `google appengine standard` (Jetty 9.4) by using `CDI`.

As `CDI` implementation I have tried `Weld` and `OpenWebBeans` but it seems it is not possible to use `CDI` on `AppEngine`.

The only framework I have been able to run has been `Guice`.

Is it possible to use `CDI` on `Google AppEngine`?

Regards.

Comment: I am not familiar with appengine but as you say it runs Jetty, I know for a fact that Weld has Jetty integration. Look at [this documentation chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#weld-servlet) for how to do it. I am not sure how closely related is jetty and google appengine so it may/may not work. Might be worth a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not familiar with google app engine, but it sound like you are missning the integration of the Servlet engine with the CDI container.

I have found this example, maybe you give it a try.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-cdi-numberguess/blob/master/pom.xml

Take a look at the pom.xml where the weld-servlet dependency is used and the web.xml which integrates Weld with the Servlet engine.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago Apache OpenWebbeans added some gae integration so it should run while you ensure it starts.

It also just got a jetty integration so maybe something to retest if you dont fear to build master?